# Wrong results with group by for distinct count

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have these two queries for calculating a distinct count from a table for a particular date range. In my first query I group by location, aRID ( which is a rule ) and date. In my second query I don't group by a date.

I am expecting the same distinct count in both the results but I get total count as 6147 in first result and 6359 in second result. What is wrong here? The difference is group by..

```
select
  r.loc 
 ,cast(r.date as DATE) as dateCol
 ,count(distinct r.dC) as dC_count
from table r
where r.date between '01-01-2018' and '06-02-2018'
and r.loc = 1
group by r.loc, r.aRId, cast(r.date as DATE)

select
r.loc 
,count(distinct r.DC) as dC_count
from table r
and r.date between '01-01-2018' and '06-02-2018'
and r.loc = 1
group by r.loc, r.aRId

loc dateCol     dC_count
1   2018-01-22  1
1   2018-03-09  2
1   2018-01-28  3
1   2018-01-05  1
1   2018-05-28  143
1   2018-02-17  1
1   2018-05-08  187
1   2018-05-31  146
1   2018-01-02  3
1   2018-02-14  1
1   2018-05-11  273
1   2018-01-14  1
1   2018-03-18  2
1   2018-02-03  1
1   2018-05-20  200
1   2018-05-14  230
1   2018-01-11  5
1   2018-01-31  1
1   2018-05-17  209
1   2018-01-20  2
1   2018-03-01  1
1   2018-01-03  3
1   2018-05-06  253
1   2018-05-26  187
1   2018-03-24  1
1   2018-02-09  1
1   2018-03-04  1
1   2018-05-03  269
1   2018-05-23  187
1   2018-05-29  133
1   2018-03-21  1
1   2018-03-27  1
1   2018-05-15  202
1   2018-03-07  1
1   2018-06-01  155
1   2018-02-21  1
1   2018-01-26  2
1   2018-02-15  2
1   2018-05-12  331
1   2018-03-10  1
1   2018-01-09  3
1   2018-02-18  1
1   2018-03-13  2
1   2018-05-09  184
1   2018-01-12  2
1   2018-03-16  1
1   2018-05-18  198
1   2018-02-07  1
1   2018-02-01  1
1   2018-01-15  3
1   2018-02-24  4
1   2018-03-19  1
1   2018-05-21  161
1   2018-02-10  1
1   2018-05-04  250
1   2018-05-30  148
1   2018-05-24  153
1   2018-01-24  1
1   2018-05-10  199
1   2018-03-08  1
1   2018-01-21  1
1   2018-05-27  151
1   2018-01-04  3
1   2018-05-07  236
1   2018-03-25  1
1   2018-03-11  2
1   2018-01-10  1
1   2018-01-30  1
1   2018-03-14  1
1   2018-02-19  1
1   2018-05-16  192
1   2018-01-13  5
1   2018-01-07  1
1   2018-03-17  3
1   2018-01-27  2
1   2018-02-22  1
1   2018-05-13  200
1   2018-02-08  2
1   2018-01-16  2
1   2018-03-03  1
1   2018-05-02  217
1   2018-05-22  163
1   2018-03-20  1
1   2018-02-05  2
1   2018-02-11  1
1   2018-01-19  2
1   2018-02-28  1
1   2018-05-05  332
1   2018-05-25  211
1   2018-03-23  1
1   2018-05-19  219

loc dC_count
1   6359
```

Comment: So, do some locations have multiple records for one or more dates?

Comment: It is 6417 in the first case (not 6147). It sounds valid to me as there are more chances to find distinct values on a "shorter" intervals.

Comment: Oh ya, it is 6417 in first case..

Answer (score 2):

From ["COUNT (Transact-SQL)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> COUNT(DISTINCT expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group, and returns the number of unique, nonnull values.

The distinct is relative to the group, not to the whole table (or selected subset). I think this might be your misconception here.

To better understand what this means, take the following simplified example:

```
CREATE TABLE group_test
             (a varchar(1),
              b varchar(1),
              c varchar(1));

INSERT INTO group_test
            (a,
             b,
             c)
            VALUES ('a',
                    'r',
                    'x'),
                   ('a',
                    's',
                    'x'),
                   ('b',
                    'r',
                    'x'),
                   ('b',
                    's',
                    'y');
```

If we `GROUP BY a` and select `count(DISTINCT c)`

```
SELECT a,
       count(DISTINCT c) #
       FROM group_test
       GROUP BY a;
```

we get

```
 a  | #
----|----
 a  |  1
 b  |  2
```

As there is only `c='x'` for `a=1`, there is only a distinct count of 1 for this group but 2 for the other group as it has `'x'`and `'y'` in `c`. The sum of counts is 3 here.

Now if we `GROUP BY a, b`

```
SELECT a,
       b,
       count(DISTINCT c) #
       FROM group_test
       GROUP BY a,
                b;
```

we get

```
 a  | b  | #
----|----|----
 a  | r  |  1
 a  | s  |  1
 b  | r  |  1
 b  | s  |  1
```

We get 1 for every count here as each value of `c` is the only one in the group. And all of a sudden the sum of counts is 4.

And if we get the distinct count of `c` for the whole table

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT c) #
       FROM group_test;
```

we get

```
 #  
----
  2
```

which sums up to 2.

The sum of the counts is different in each case but right none the less.

The more groups there are, the higher the chance for a value to be unique within that group. So your results seem totally plausible.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=40805a103c7664d9b7b1077ef08173d0)

Comment: yeah this looks correct, but then how do I fix it? I need to have it grouped by day.

Comment: @user1821499: What do you mean "fix it"? If it's correct there's no need to fix anything? Maybe you want to ask a new question including the tables (as `CREATE TABLE` statements please), some sample data (as `INSERT INTO`) and a detailed description what you actually wan to achieve illustrated by an expected result set according to the provided sample data.